# Trying to get sum of specific column cells for last 4 rows sum in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get sum of capacity column of last 4 rows of a table in MySQL.

My Table is :

[image]

My SQL is :

```
SELECT
tid,
sum(capacity)
FROM captable 
ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 4
```

Result is giving different sum. It should be 150+200+250+300 = 900.

[image]

I am looking for sum of the red circled numbers.

Comment: Do you have any pattern for identifying last 4 records?

Comment: Your query has the sum of the 4 values you require and also `tid` - exactly what value of `tid` would you want to see here and why?

Comment: Hi Stu, you are right. I cleared tid.

Comment: I need last for records to identify total capacity. Every hour ne 4 rows are added. So last 4 rows always give latest capacity total information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could order using subquery and apply `SUM` in the outer query. This query take in consideration that tid is auto_inrement:

```
SELECT sum(t1.capacity)
FROM ( SELECT tid,capacity
       FROM captable
       ORDER BY  tid DESC LIMIT 4
      ) as t1 ;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> last_4_rows_sum
> 900
> ```

[Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9475acb7a53fb99213f9a2af18eabe58)

Comment: Thanks Ergest. This also solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub query,

```
SELECT tid,
sum(capacity)
from
(SELECT
tid,
capacity
FROM captable 
ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 4) tbl;
```

You can also use row_number() if required,

```
SELECT tid,
sum(capacity)
from
(SELECT
tid,
capacity,
row_number() over(order by capacity desc) as rnk
FROM captable) tbl where rnk between 1 and 4;
```

Comment: Hi Jim, first one solved my problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You provided `tid, sum(capacity)` in your SELECT statement, which means you will get the sum **for each** tid that exists.

Since each tid apparently exists only once in your dataset (at least in your image), I assume you get the same values returned from the table.

If you're interested in the sum, no matter which tid, then simply remove the tid column from the statement, like this:

```sql
SELECT
sum(capacity)
FROM captable 
ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 4
```